# Intellij Plugin - Androidx Libs as aar files cannot find the sources

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, androidx, intellij-plugin

I am working on a plugin to get more knowledge on how they work. I am trying to add this in the gradle file implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'.

The project does not handle the aar file for some reason and I cannot use the ViewModel class because the import does not exist.

What could be wrong with the set up?

Comment: If you're modifying the build.gradle file programmatically, you need to trigger a Gradle sync before the class becomes available for the IDE.

Comment: @yole I have done that but I only get access to specific files. The ViewModel class is not there for some reason

Comment: Same here. I still have not found a way.